# Induction proof for gcd(a,b), and s, t

Tags: induction, gcd-and-lcm

**Show that if a ≥ b > 0, and gcd(a,b)=d, and a*s+b*t=d, then the values s and t satisfy:
|s| ≤ b/d and |t| ≤ a/d
Hint: prove by induction on b: be careful, you have to stop the induction before b gets to zero, so the last step to consider is when b | a.**

I think the base case is b=1, but I can't seem to find how to even show that this is true for b=1.

Also, in the hint: "the last step to consider is when b | a"- why not just "when b=1"?

Comment: I don't think you are doing induction on $b =1$ and for all natural $b$.  But on all $b = kd$.  IF it's true for $b=kd$ then prove it is true for $b = (k-1)d$ and so on down to $b = d$ (i.e. $b|a$).

Comment: Oh!! so what is my base case?